# Guessing Projects How to add guess limit Python

Tags: python

```
import random

real_num = random.randrange(1,50)
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))

while guess != real_num:
    if guess < real_num:
        print("Guess higher")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
    else:
        print("Guess lower")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
print("YOU WIN")
```

Hi, I would like to add a limit for this game and I have tried several attempts but the results does not seems not be working. Thank you for the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is `random.randrange(1,50)` uses numbers from 1 till 49 only.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Is there any ways to improve my python skills efficiently?

Comment: Just go with the module docs. Explore new stuff. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a variable to track how many attempts have been tried and just add that as a condition to break out of the `while` loop. You can also set a limit variable to check the guess count against each iteration.

**Edit:** you also want to make sure when breaking out of the loop if the user went over the limit -- my initial answer didn't take this into account so it would've said "Too many guesses! YOU WIN"

Edited snippet:

```
import random

real_num = random.randrange(1,50)
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))

guess_count = 0 # keep track of guesses
guess_limit = 10 # set to whatever you want

while guess != real_num:
    # check first if there were too many guesses
    if guess_count >= guess_limit:
        print("Too many guesses!")
        break

    # otherwise carry on with regular game logic
    if guess < real_num:
        print("Guess higher")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
    else:
        print("Guess lower")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))

    # if we reach this point, it was an incorrect guess
    # increment guess count here
    guess_count += 1

# check to see if the user guessed too many times
if guess_count >= guess_limit:
    print("YOU LOSE")
else:
    print("YOU WIN")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. This answer is perfect. Appreciate a lot.

Comment: Glad to help! There's a lot of good other ways of thinking about solving this problem in the other answers as well, you can see there's always a bunch of different ways to achieve a similar result :)

Answer (score 0):

Really all you need is a counter with each guess

```
import random

real_num = random.randrange(1,50)
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
attempts = 0 #

while guess != real_num and attempts < 10: # checking if attempts is less than the max (10)
    if guess < real_num:
        print("Guess higher")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
        attempts+=1
    elif guess == real_num:  # checking if the guess is equal to the answer
        print("YOU WIN")
        break               # break to stop the game
    else:
        print("Guess lower")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
        attempts+=1
```

All we are doing here is checking if we are still under the max attempts, and if the attempt is wrong we add one to the attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the total number of allowed attempts in a variable. For each guess, decrement the value of that variable by one.

```
import random


real_num = random.randrange(1, 50)
total_attempts = 3
while True:
    guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
    if guess == real_num:
        break
    total_attempts -= 1
    if total_attempts == 0:
        break
    if guess < real_num:
        print("Guess higher")        
    else:
        print("Guess lower")    

if total_attempts != 0:
    print("YOU WIN")
else:
    print("YOU LOST")
```

Output:

```
Enter a number between 1 to 50: 23
Guess lower
Enter a number between 1 to 50: 12
Guess lower
Enter a number between 1 to 50: 4
YOU LOST
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```py
import random

real_num = random.randrange(1,50)
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
guess_limit = 10

while guess != real_num:
    if guess_limit == 0:
        print("Guess limit reached")
        exit(0)
    
    if guess < real_num:
        print("Guess higher")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
    else:
        print("Guess lower")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))

    guess_limit -= 1


print("YOU WIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
import random

limit=5
is_win=Fasle
real_num = random.randrange(1,50)
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
   
for i in range(1,limit):
    if guess==real_num:
        print("YOU WIN")
        is_win=True
    elif guess<real_num:
        print("Guess higher | Number of times remaining :",(limit-i))
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))
    elif guess>real_num:
        print("Guess lower | Number of times remaining :",(limit-i))
        guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 50: "))

if is_win==False:
    print("Unfortunately you did not win")
```

output :

```
Enter a number between 1 to 50: 10                                                                                              
Guess higher | Number of times remaining : 4
...
```